# Servers Not Showing Up in Windows Explorer

Tags: windows-7, windows-explorer, samba, windows-server-2012, ubuntu-server

I've got 2 servers at my house (Ubuntu 13.10 & Windows 2012). After renaming the servers, they aren't showing up on any of the Windows computers. Any ideas why this is happening? I've restarted the client computers, restarted both servers, etc. All that said, I can connect to them by navigation to \servername in Windows Explorer.

Doubting it's a Samba/Windows Server issue since a) it is affecting them both and b) they were previously working.

Comment: do they show in `net view` or `smbtree`? does `nbtstat -R` on the windows boxes resolve the issue for that client?

Comment: I'm not seeing them anywhere in Windows, except when I explicitly navigate there in explorer.